# Download file from file sharing path using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm try to download file from link like file://SharePath\filename.pdf using javascript, but browser always block link file://.
There is any way to do that?

Comment: You can download file when you host your html file to web server.

Comment: <a href="url of file or location">download</a>

Comment: It's `file://`, not `file:\\\`

Comment: I already try using <a href="url of file or location">download</a> but not working. Browser always block connection when i try open new tab with link is file://

Answer (score 0):

Please use "file:///" before giving the path of the directory. Also, use "/" & "\" properly.

Here is the working solution in my system,

```html
<br/>
<a href="file:///C:\Users\105800\Downloads\Systems - Casinolink - Slot.pdf" download>Download</a>
<br/>
```

follow this link
https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server

Please revert back for any issues.